# How to turn off HTML5 Offline caching

Tags: html, offline-caching, offline-browsing

I've been using HTML5 Offline caching on my website for a while and for some reasons I am considering turning it off. To my surprise it doesn't work.

This is how I've implemented HTML5 Offline caching.

In my `index.html` I give path to the manifest file

```
<html manifest="app.manifest">
```

In the app.manifest file I list all the js/css/png file that I would like to be cached by the browser for offline usage. Every time I deploy updates, I update the app.manifest file, which causes the browser to fetch latest version of all the files listed in the manifest file.

In order to turn off the offline caching, I changed my index.html's opening tag to

```
<html>
```

I made a dummy change to app.manifest file, so that browser (which has already cached my website), will detect the change and download latest version of all the files (including index.html).

What I noticed is, the browser indeed gets the latest version of all the files. I see the new `<html>` tag in the updated version without the manifest declaration, however the behavior of the browser for future changes does not change. i.e. I now expect the browser to immediately fetch the new version of the index.html file, when it's changed on server. However that doesn't happen. The browser doesn't download updated index.html until I make any changes to the manifest file.

Thus it appears to me that the browser has permanently associated app.manifest file with my website URL and it won't get rid of it even when I don't mention it in `<html>` tag.

I have tested this on both Google Chrome and Firefox, same results. I also tried restarting Chrome, but it won't forget that my site ever had app.manifest defined for it. I haven't found any discussion on this aspect of offline caching on the web.

**Update**: I managed to get rid of the behavior in Chrome by clearing all the browsing data (by going to settings). But that's not something I can tell the users to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the *manifest* URL return a 404 to indicate you don't want offline web applications anymore. According to Step 5 of [HTML5 §5.6.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#downloading-or-updating-an-application-cache), this marks the cache as obsolete, and will remove it.

You can also manually delete the offline web application in Chrome by going to `about:appcache-internals`.

Comment: Fabulous. In the past I had tried removing app.manifest from server and that hadn't worked. I tried it again and dumped the headers only to find that it wasn't returning 404, but a 302 to a 404 redirect page. After I changed the server to explicitly return 404, the offline cache expired alright. Thanks!

Comment: That's also very useful if you want to disable caching for a certain condition. Great tip!!!!!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I tried &lt;html manifest="IGNORE.manifest"> (where IGNORE.manifest does not exist and returns a 404). The app (which at one point got cached) is still being displayed in both Chrome and my Android browser. Did I do the right thing?

Comment: @antun The manifest URL is the first (and if the manifest hasn't changed, *only*) thing that's queries by the browser. Changing parts of the application (like the index page) has no effect. You must configure the server to return a 404 for the *old* manifest URL.

Comment: Thanks. But in addition to changing the manifest attribute, I also deleted the *old* manifest file (which was called cache.manifest) from the server. So if I try to access it, I do get an HTTP 404. I've tested on various devices, and they all continue to cache the old version of the app regardless. (In Chrome, I can delete the app cache manually, and I see the new site. But I can't do this in my mobile devices).

Comment: @antun That would mean a gross violation of the spec. If you intercept the traffic from the device, what requests and responses do you see? Can you post a link to a pcap file? If this is reproducible (i.e. you can post a link to a site demonstrating it), feel free to post a new question about that, and link it here.